# Class list covert into dataframe by groups

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have one database the type is `<class 'list'>`: `[a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, c1, c2, c3, c4, c5,....]`

Hope the result to convert into a dataframe: (each 5 items in one group)

[image]

Could someone help me and the method hope to learn from you?

Answer (score 1):

Try with `numpy` `reshape`, `l` is your `list` here

```
import numpy as np 

out = pd.DataFrame(np.array(l).reshape((-1,5)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `numpy.reshape` and then create a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.reshape(l, (-1, 5)))
```

Output:

```
>>> df
    0   1   2   3   4
0  a1  a2  a3  a4  a5
1  b1  b2  b3  b4  b5
2  c1  c2  c3  c4  c5

>>> df[2]
0    a3
1    b3
2    c3
Name: 2, dtype: object
```